# Automating Web Search on a Page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

Here is my code (at the final stage):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BBC_W_FCast_New_01
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Instantiate Firefox Driver
            var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather");

            //Using the 'Find a Forecast' search field to get the weather in 'Reading, UK'
            var user = driver.FindElement(By.Id("locator-form-search"));

            //Use "Reading, Reading" to avoid ambiguity. There is a location called Reading in USA
            user.SendKeys("Reading, Reading");

            //Click on Search button
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("locator-form-submit")).Click();

            //Click on Table button
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("detail-table-view")).Click();

            //Obtaining pressure For 2100 hours today
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='hourly']/div[3]/table/tfoot/tr[3]/td[10]")).Click();

            //Obtain pressure for 2100 Hours tomorrow
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='hourly']/div[3]/table/tfoot/tr[3]/td[16]")).Click();

            //Subtract the two values above and then 'echo' the result in Selenium
            int val1 = Int32.Parse(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='hourly']/div[3]/table/tfoot/tr[3]/td[16]")).Text);
            int val2 = Int32.Parse(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='hourly']/div[3]/table/tfoot/tr[3]/td[10]")).Text);

            int difference = val1 - val2;
            System.Console.WriteLine("Difference is: " + difference);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screen Shot Error]

Comment: This looks like some form of homework question. It might help if you reformulated it more to show which parts you are actually stuck on. Like - can you not work out how to create a WebElement ?

Comment: SlightlyKosumi, thank you very much for your prompt response. I have added the code I have been able to write. In the question area above, I have also highlighted where I seem to be stuck. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, for the place where I am stuck, I cannot use the Id identifier to select/identify 21:00. Instead, I am stuck with an HTML identifier.

Your advice will be highly appreciated.
 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a homework assignment, so I'm not going to give you any code examples, but I can give you some direction.

For each of the elements on the page you want to use, you will have to find them using a locator (id/name/class/xpath) which you can find by right-clicking the element on the page and selecting 'Inspect Element' or something similar.

- For searching, you will need to input or send values to an element. **When a command is loading a page or initiates a dynamic page update, look to use dynamic waits like the following:**
- `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.‌​id("locator")));`
- For expanding, you will need to click an element.
- For obtaining, you will need to find the element and the get the value.
  *In this case*, I would suggest using xpath since there isn't a better identifier. If you use Chrome, when you inspect the value, right click the value in the Elements tab of the developer tool and click 'Copy' > 'Copy Xpath'.  You will also need to click on the next day (again suggest xpath) to find the Pressure for tomorrow.
- Be sure to assign the needed values to variables so you can use them later(**hint: look to *get values or get text***).  Once you have the variables with the times, I believe you can use `echo <answer here>`

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.In the Question area, I have added the code I have been able to write. I have also highlighted where I seem to be stuck. Thank you very much. Much appreciated.

Comment: Also, for the place where I am stuck, I cannot use the Id identifier to select/identify 21:00. Instead, I am stuck with an HTML identifier.

Your advice will be highly appreciated.
 
Thank you very much.

Comment: I've added some information to my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Swagin19, I have edited my code after following your directions... Much, much appreciated. I am just at the final step - of subtracting the numbers and echoing in Selenium. I know I am to use the subtract operator.  For example, after declaring the variables, use x-y = 

Then, use the Echo command.

Thanks once again.

Comment: I have added an addition comment to my answer.  I'm not positive on the echo part though since I don't have much experience with c#

Comment: Swagin9, thanks once again, and, apologies for the delay in responding. I have updated the code (after running a build of the code successfully in MS/Visual Studio. But, I am getting an error message. 

I would be most grateful if you could take a look, please.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Let me add quickly that to trouble shoot, I have double checked the Id of the element before proceeding. I also tried using the XPath & I got the same error. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are using the right if there, but when you click the search button there is a delay before that element is present on the page. You'll want to look at using a webdriverwait to make sure that elect is present or visible before trying to perform the click.

Comment: So, I can use this ? 

driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); ??

Thank you.

Comment: That should accomplish the desired result, but I have updated my answer with a better type of wait that will check at regular intervals to see if the element is on the page rather than a static 10-second wait.